# Android Studio now shows this error

Tags: android, android-studio

Hi i made android app project everything worked well with compile with android N 7.0 api 24

now when i restarted the Android Studio after some time
my main activity and resources shows error ?

```
C:\Users\Hella\AndroidStudioProjects\Z\app\src\main\res\values-v21\styles.xml
Error:(3, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowActionBar'.
Error:(3, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowNoTitle'.
C:\Users\Hella\AndroidStudioProjects\Z\app\src\main\res\values\styles.xml
Error:No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowActionBar'.
Error:No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowNoTitle'.
Error:(4, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorAccent'.
Error:(4, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimary'.
Error:(4, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimaryDark'.
C:\Users\Hella\AndroidStudioProjects\Z\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values\values.xml
Error:(11) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
Error:(17) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar'.
Error:(22) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light'.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Hella\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\24.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

**PS my dependencies shows nothing i havenot added any appcompat support as when i created new project with android 7 compile n target it automatically extended activity to appcompat ,it was fine ,all build was successfull but just after restart it cant resolve appcompatactivity**

Comment: it looks like your styles xml and values xml is just missing some attributes, you could try a clean and rebuild, or just check your styles for windowActionBar, windowNoTitle, etc.

Comment: hello doesnot fix PS my dependencies shows nothing i havenot added any appcompat support as when i created new project with android 7 compile n target it automatically extended activity to appcompat ,it was fine ,all build was successfull but just after restart it cant resolve appcompatactivity

Comment: make sure your build.gradle is pointing to 24 as well?

Comment: compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.1'  yes

Comment: I had a similar issue with appcompat when L preview first came out. Can you confirm that those xmls exist in their respective folders?

Comment: hi zion i have posted reply as answer see below i figure it out ,Android Studio has alot of bugs

Answer (score -1):

When I restarted Android Studio, and loaded my project, the dependencies were deleted automatically

I made a new project and found that the below dependencies weren't there:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-alpha2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0-alpha2'
```

Android Studio is full of bugs,i wish eclipse get support back

Comment: Eclipse Neon does have Android Support.. But your problem is Gradle related, so the IDE does not really matter